# Security Essentials scheduled scan less often than weekly

Tags: windows-7, ms-security-essentials

Is it possible to schedule Microsoft Security Essentials to do a scan less often than once per week?

This is not officially supported through the UI (it only offers day of the week selection), but is there an alternative way?

I'm using a hybrid hard drive and the manufacturer recommends not doing virus scans too often, since it reduces performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open the Task Scheduler (`taskschd.msc`) and manually edit the Security Essentials schedule. It is labeled *MP Scheduled Scan* under *Task Scheduler Library→Microsoft→Microsoft Antimalware*:

[image]
[image]
[image]